# Match field value of parameter from the same dataset using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset FiscalYearMonth which contains

```
Fiscalmonthyear
Fiscalmonthkey
```

I have also `Parameters!FiscalYearMonth.Value`

How can I get `Fiscalmonthkey` for FiscalYearMonth parameter ? I tried the following expression but didn't work

```
=lookup(Fields!FiscalMonthYear.Value,Parameters!FiscalYearMonth.Value, Fields!FiscalMonthKey.Value, "FiscalYearMonth")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your function parameters in the wrong order, try this:

```
=lookup(Parameters!FiscalYearMonth.Value, Fields!FiscalMonthYear.Value, Fields!FiscalMonthKey.Value, "FiscalYearMonth")
```

This bascially says "in the dataset 'FiscalYearMonth', compare the value of Parameters!FiscalYearMonth.Value to the field Fields!FiscalMonthYear.Value for each row in the dataset and return the value of Fields!FiscalMonthKey.Value where there is a match".

Note that the Lookup() function only returns a single value and will stop at the first match found.